# We are running a map reduce/spark job to bulk load hbase data in One of the environment

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

We are running a `map reduce/spark` job to bulk load `hbase` data in one of the environments.

While running it, connection to the `hbase zookeeper` cannot initialize throwing the following error.

```
    16/05/10 06:36:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=c321shu.int.westgroup.com:2181,c149jub.int.westgroup.com:2181,c167rvm.int.westgroup.com:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x74b47a30, quorum=c321shu.int.westgroup.com:2181,c149jub.int.westgroup.com:2181,c167rvm.int.westgroup.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
    16/05/10 06:36:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server c321shu.int.westgroup.com/10.204.152.28:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    16/05/10 06:36:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.204.24.16:35740, server: c321shu.int.westgroup.com/10.204.152.28:2181
    16/05/10 06:36:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server c321shu.int.westgroup.com/10.204.152.28:2181, sessionid = 0x5534bebb441bd3f, negotiated timeout = 60000
    16/05/10 06:36:11 INFO mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2: Looking up current regions for table ecpdevv1patents:NormNovusDemo
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:
    Tue May 10 06:36:11 CDT 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@3927df20, java.io.IOException: Call to c873gpv.int.westgroup.com/10.204.67.9:60020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
```

We have executed the same job in `Titan DEV` too but facing the same problem. Please let us know if anyone has faced the same problem before.

Details are,

•   Earlier job was failing to connect to `localhost/127.0.0.1:2181`. Hence only the property `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` has been set in map reduce code with `c149jub.int.westgroup.com,c321shu.int.westgroup.com,c167rvm.int.westgroup.com` which we got from `hbase-site.xml`.
•   We are using jars of cdh `version 5.3.3`.

Comment: I have seen something similar, it was due to the way I was trying to write to hbase. don't remember exactly, but I think it was due to wrong hbase table name/ column family. can you post the part of your code where you are writing to hbase

Comment: In HFileOutputFormat2  --> configureIncrementalLoad() method you have this issue. After "looking message" there is another info which needs to be printed. I think you have region problems like  Regions in transition... pls see below code  // Use table's region boundaries for TOP split points. 
489     LOG.info("Looking up current regions for table " + regionLocator.getName()); 
490     List<ImmutableBytesWritable> startKeys = getRegionStartKeys(regionLocator); 
491     LOG.info("Configuring " + startKeys.size() + " reduce partitions " + 
492         "to match current region count");

Comment: Here are some pointers 1) please check h-master url for this table and paste the screen shot 2) what is your row key format is it been salted to avoid hots spotting ? 3) please check .meta table also 4) are you able to access this and insert one dummy record manually i.e from shell ?